# Scrapy's Initialization error

Tags: python, scrapy

I am getting started with Scrapy, but I have two problems with installation on Linux Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu based version).

1. I don't get which is the difference from installing `pip install
   scrapy` and `sudo apt-get install scrapy`
2. When i do install one of the two and I try to follow the first tutorial of Scrapy  using the command `scrapy startproject tutorial`it gives me error `/usr/bin: No such file or directory`.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall many times but still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please edit you question and add what OS / version you are trying to install scrapy?

Comment: I am on Linux Mint 17.2 (Ubuntu based version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Instalation Source

Both commands `pip install scrapy` and `sudo apt-get install scrapy` will install Scrapy on your computer, but the versions may be different. The pip option installs the latest version for Scrapy 1.0, while the one in your repositories its probably outdated.

If anyway you want to install the package from the repositories and still keep it updated, you can add the Scrapy repository:

```
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/ubuntu.html
echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee /etc/apt-sources.list.d/scrapy.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy
```

Souce: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/ubuntu.html

#### 2. Check the PATH variable

Depending on the way you install Scrapy, the binaries folder for the installation might be different. In my case I have it in `/usr/local/bin`.
Display your PATH variable with `echo "$PATH"`, and check if the folder with the Scrapy binary is included.

You can add more directories to the variable with `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`

Answer (score 1):

The [installation guide](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#ubuntu-9-10-or-above) tells not to use the packages provided by Ubuntu:

> Don’t use the python-scrapy package provided by Ubuntu, they are
>   typically too old and slow to catch up with latest Scrapy.
>
> Instead, use the official [Ubuntu
>   Packages](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu),
>   which already solve all dependencies for you and are continuously
>   updated with the latest bug fixes.

As mentioned you should install it using the [Ubuntu packages on this page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu) instead.

Besides the previous steps, I also had to install `service-identity`:

```
sudo pip install service-identity
```